# get std::function to deduce pass by reference/pass by value

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm writing a template function that takes an std::function as input and does some processing of the function. I'd like a way to automatically handle any function, but I'm having trouble with pass-by-reference in type deduction.

The kind of functions I use are general, the argument list varies as well as the types. Here's a reproducer

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono> //c++11
#include <functional> //c++11

using namespace std;
// for use with functions passing by value
  template<typename T_Out, typename... T_Args>
    inline int get_stats( T_Out f(T_Args...), T_Args&... args)
    {
      f(args...);
      return 0;
    }

int foo(int x, double y)
{ return 0; }

int goo(int& x, double& y)
{ return 0; }

int hoo(int x , double& y)
{ return 0; }


int main()
{

  int x = 42;
  double y = 0.0;
  cout << get_stats( foo, x, y) << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The above template works on `foo`, and I can get `hoo` to work if I replace `f(T_Args...)` with `f(T_Args&...)`, but I'm not able to get hoo to work without explicitly writing a template to match the pass-by type, which at that point I might as well not use templates at all.

How can I handle the pass-by type automatically? Further, It'd be nice to be able to automatically handle prvalues as well. I'd like to restrict this to c++11 if possible as well.

Comment: Please include as much real code as possible.  Your "looks like" doesn't compile, period, for any of your cases.  [MCVE] are key here, to see what you are doing wrong, and also to get a better idea of what you want.  What types do you want deduced?  Are you going to use the args elsewhere?  If you are just taking arguments to pass to a function, why not follow single responsibility principle and ask the caller to pass you a lambda with the arguments already bound?

Comment: Sounds like you need perfect forwarding: https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/perfect-forwarding-and-universal-references-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually you need to combine two previous answers. KorelK's answer to avoid trying to deduce exact signature of passed functor and CJ13's answer to use perfect forwarding:

```
template<typename T_Func, typename ...T_Args>
inline int get_stats(T_Func f, T_Args&&... args)
{
    return f(std::forward<T_Args>(args)...);
}
```

[Online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/OkQOsQudxdAJtM8P)

Answer (score 0):

Editted in response to better solution:

What you want to use here is what Scott Meyers calls the universal reference:

```
template<typename T_Out, typename... T_Args>
inline T_Out get_stats( T_Out f, T_Args&&... args)
{
  return f(std::forward<T_Args>(args)...);
}
```

When a template parameter is followed by the double ampersand, it will either be a lvalue reference or an rvalue reference based on what you pass it. You then call std::forward which will continue the use of the proper kind of reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
template<typename T_Func, typename ...T_Args>
inline int get_stats(T_Func f, T_Args&&... args)
{
    return f(args...);
}

int foo(int x, double y)
{ return x + y; }

int goo(int& x, double& y)
{ return x - y; }

int hoo(int x , double& y)
{ return x * y; }


int main()
{

    int x = 42;
    double y = 1.5;
    cout << get_stats(foo, x, y) << endl;
    cout << get_stats(goo, x, y) << endl;
    cout << get_stats(hoo, x, y) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `get_stats(foo, 0, 0);` -> `error: no matching function for call to 'get_stats' `

Comment: @AndriyTylychko you right, that's because I use a lvalue parameters, you can use lvalue reference as I as changed it now.

Comment: now you still need perfect forwarding otherwise you can end up copying expensive values